# Use ASP.NET MVC for html brochure websites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a project that will basically be a large brochure html website. Although some content could possibly be database driven in the future. I use ASP.NET MVC for any database driven websites usually, but not sure whether to use it for brochure html websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably want to use Master Pages even if the content is static. Might as well use MVC to keep headers and footers consistent across the site. (Same goes for any language, really.)

Answer (score 1):

You host only plain old html files in it for now. If the need arises for database-driven  content, ASP.NET MVC's routing options make it easy to switch to a dynamic site without breaking the links.

We used the same approach for setting up a dummy website for SEO purposes until the real app was developed and the switch to dynamic content was effortless.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about ASP.NET MVC (as apposed to Webforms? I assume you're asking) is that you can just use basic html and have a designer design up brochure required. If this needs to be more "dynamic" at some stage with forms or CMS etc, using the existing plain html will be easier.

Also if you're using MVC already its a no-brainer...

Comment: I should have been abit clearer, I was comparing MVC to "html only" for the project (not to webforms)

Comment: ok, I see, no probs. I would recommend using existing hosting, deployment and maintenance procedures to ensure consistency. This ensures the same level of service for all websites and enables seamless scalablility...

Answer (score 0):

Danny,

it's possibly also a choice over whether your project sponsor is wanting to pay for windows hosting or whether they go down the linux route. if you know for sure that the site would NEVER be required to take data from a database then you could actually create an app in mvc (your developer app) and then have that app generate the 'flat file' site out to html files. that way, you could store the elements that make up the content in your developer database and regenerate the entire site when required.  This approach would reap dividends - for example you decided to add some jquery across the site, then this would do it all in a single hit.

this way of generating flat sites would mean that you could in theory have an engine that you used for multiple clients, changing only the css and content as required.

just my tuppence worth...

jim